# Testing a circuit systematically and efficiently

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, simulation, isolation, test

I need to determine a circuit's response to variations in component values. What are common go-to methods for this?

**Background**: I'm a growing novice in electronics design. So, my question is about common, de facto strategies accepted by experienced hobbyists and professionals alike. What for? To analyze how a circuit behaves for different combinations of its components' values (and other parameters). And to do so in a structured, systematic, efficient way.

My first thought is a SPICE simulation. But I would like to confirm whether this is 'it' or whether there are other approaches that I'm unaware of.

**Context**: I have a simple optocoupler circuit as shown below. The left side (1) operates on a different potential than the right (2). And a MCU on the right needs to read an analog signal on the left (`V_ana_1`). Hence the optocoupler. I use it to convert `V_ana_1` to `V_ana_2` which then is fed to the MCU.

Now the optocoupler's response is not linear. So I would like to **choose `R1` and `R2` such that** `V_ana_2`'s range falls within the sensitive (as opposed to the saturated) region of this response for a given `V_ana_1` range of, say, 2-3 V.

What's a good way to go about doing this without physically and manually trying out different resistor values? (Which is what I did, which is why I'm asking this question - that was a pain.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzwURr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Woah, thats a lot to take in all in one question. Please see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . In the future, keep questions specific and not broad. The last question is good.

Comment: This is a pretty bad example. Take a look at the datasheet of a typical optocoupler. You will see _massive_ variations in the electrical specifications. No matter what resistor you select, it will only be good for a single board. If you want to transfer analog signals with an optocoupler you would use two matched ones, so you can have some feedback.

Comment: Or a linear optocoupler: (like this one)[http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf], which what they were designed for.  This one has two optocouplers in the same package to allow for feedback.

Comment: @laptop2d - That link says nothing about brevity. And regarding specificity, the optocoupler case is just an illustrative example of a larger, general question that I'm asking.

Comment: @pipe - On the left side is a third-party board that I'm 'hacking' into. I don't have control over it, so would inserting a feedback mechanism work here?

Comment: @AndrewSpott - see comment above, please.

Comment: @oswinium you don't have to be brief but this question is opinion based "What are common go-to methods for this?" and vauge. Its usually good to keep the number of questions to promote specific answers, had you ask just the first question, this post might have been closed (which isn't a bad thing, it just means people can't answer it)

Comment: Well, you can have a +1 from me anyway for defensive questioning; I think people are too critical of questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is preferable to use intuition and basic calculations rather than blindly swapping components in and out.

For your example, you have an optocoupler, and you want to take a voltage on one side and transfer it to another.  As I mentioned in the comments, this is not the greatest tool for this (a linear optocoupler would be much better), and the part to part variations make this likely not work.

[Here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1727610.pdf) is the FOD852 optocoupler.  It was the first datasheet the popped up when I searched for optocoupler.  On the 4th page is a number of figures that show the characteristics of a particular device.

Figure 8 shows a plot of collector to emitter voltage as a function of collector current, for a number of different forward currents of the diode.  We know that we want some range of currents through the diode to equal some range of currents (or voltage) through the transistor:

[image: Figure 8]

We can kind of squint and see that a current of ~3-10 mA will lead to a collector current of ~80-100 mA.

So, we want to generate a 3-10mA current through the diode, and we want a 80-100mA current through a resistor to give us a Vce of ~1V.

The 3-10mA is accomplished with a resistor of (Avg(V_ana1) - V_f)/6mA,  The 80-100mA is accomplished with a resistor with a value of (Vcc2 - 1V)/90mA.

By thinking a little, and using the data available to us, we can make a pretty good guess.

Comment: Is it common practice, then, to take the average / midpoint of the voltage or current ranges?

Comment: It's certainly best to start near the middle rather than at one end - things may go nonlinear at the edges, or you run out of graph.

Comment: Expanding on what @pjc50 said, you should ensure that the whole range that you are interested in is appropriate:  you will want to make sure that both (max(V_ana1) - V_f)/R and (min(V_ana1) - V_f)/R are within the current range that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

- The best way is to apply worst case tolerances over T and V with some margin for vendor variation, aging must be done for reliable production designs.
- Often specs for worst case V are given for CMOS at Vcc-10% at 25'C and over T range.
- if design cannot meet worst case then Monte Carlo methods for parameters like dielectric constant of PCB on controlled impedances, trace accuracy etc. or pay for TDR coupon tests done for Zo.
- The best way to verify a design is test to functional failure (HASS) during DVT to determine margins and root cause. e.g. vary Xtal f over spec range incl tolerance at 25'C and temp. by injection and Vmin at cycle temps with high RH with vibration to board.
- Every test should have a margin budget verified, e.g. comparator asymmetry, regulator error margin etc, surge or ripple current/rating, noise margin, timing margin, real-time stack margin, buffer overflow margin etc etc.
- the best design has DFT and these parameters defined in the design spec. then DVT is easier to perform. DVT= Design Validation Test. DFT=Design for Testability). This enables good fault detection/isolation for self-Test, Functional(FT) and In-cct test(ICT) then sys test.
- Once the functional design is verified, solderability is the #1 cause of poor yields, which gets into bad design, process, or procedure
- Each test should fit onto 1 page with method illustrated and equip. used

Comment: +1 for Monte Carlo. You need to be careful with the results though. The measured mean follows a normal distribution, and the measured variance a chi squared one, provided you have normally distributed parameters.

Comment: Yes then when Monte Carlo methods fail to yield optimum yields, use Taguchi methods and DoE by varying all pertinent variables parameter +/-10% simultaneously in a small number of experiments to determine margins and sensitivity to each parameter with overall functional result.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method is to use SPICE simulator. Go here,

http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice

Download and install. It is free. 
It has many examples for starters, including optocouplers.

Briefly, every element of schematics can be represented by a realistic parameter (SPICE) model, extracted by part manufacturer. The simulator then calculates EVERYTHING depending on type of stimulus applied to circuit inputs. For commercial-grade simulator it would calculate everything for all temperature and voltage corners of the parts. LTspice will give you results for typical parameters. Read tutorials and enjoy the journey.